# WebView controls not working / how to implement scroll and tap

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using web view to display html text on my application. I need the user to be able to scroll and tap the text. However That seems to be close to impossible. TapGesture is just not firing and based on my search its not mistake on my side but seems that since webview its usually used to display web pages and they include buttons to no need for tap gesture. So if i use my custom control it work however i cant scroll the content and if i use scroll around the webview then it doenst work as needed. Once i implemented the custom control i can see then action in my output however the content doesnt move.

```
public class ExtendedWebView : WebView
    {
        public ExtendedWebView()
        {
        }

        public event EventHandler Touched;

        public void OnTouched() =>
        Touched?.Invoke(this, null);
        public ICommand PannedCommand
        {
            set { SetValue(PannedCommandProperty, value); }
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(PannedCommandProperty); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty PannedCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PannedCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(ExtendedWebView));
    }

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedWebView), typeof(ExtendedWebViewRenderer))]
namespace AVAT.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class ExtendedWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public static int _webViewHeight;
        static ExtendedWebView _xwebView = null;
        public WebView _webView;
        bool isScroll;
        public ExtendedWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
           
        }
     
        class ExtendedWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            WebView _webView;
            public async override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
            {
                try
                {
                    _webView = view;
                    if (_xwebView != null)
                    {

                        view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        string result = await _xwebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()");
                        _xwebView.HeightRequest = Convert.ToDouble(result);


                    }
                    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            _xwebView = e.NewElement as ExtendedWebView;
            _webView = Control;
          
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                _webView.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendedWebViewClient());
            }
            _webView.Touch += (object sender, TouchEventArgs eventArgs) =>
            {

                if (eventArgs.Event.Action == Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Down)
                {
                    var webview = Element as ExtendedWebView;
             
                    webview.OnTouched();
                }
            };
            _webView.Touch += _webView_Touch;

            void _webView_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
            {
                var webview = Element as ExtendedWebView;
                bool isMove = true;
                Console.WriteLine(e.Event.Action);
                switch (e.Event.Action)
                {
                    case Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Down:

                        isScroll = true;
                        break;
                    case Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Move:
                        isScroll = true;
                        if (isMove)
                        {
                            isMove = false;
                            webview.PannedCommand?.Execute(null);
                        }
                        break;
                    case Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Up:

                        if (!isScroll)
                        {
                            webview.OnTouched();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Xaml

```
  <controls:ExtendedWebView
                                        x:Name="webView"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        Source="{Binding CZ, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Touched="webView_Touched"/>
```

Maybe you guys have experience how to implement both controls tap and scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I create a html page with button click event. Please check the way used to load the html.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .label {
        width: 800px;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }

    .button {
        width: 800px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<label class="label" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">
    Click Me! This is a text label.
</label>
<button class="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">
   button click
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Code: The code used to load the html for webview.

```
   string fileName = "XamarinDemo.webview.html";

        var assembly = typeof(XamarinDemo.MainPage).Assembly;

        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName);
        if (stream == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                String.Format("Cannot create stream from specified URL: {0}", fileName));
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string htmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        HtmlWebViewSource html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        html.Html = htmlString;

        Webview_html.Source = html;
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: the code should be in the back of the contentpage that contains the webview?

Comment: I have this but it doesnt work string result = await _xwebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.onclick;})()" when i click on the text

Comment: Or what about the panned command? I cant find any documentation to that

Comment: The onclick event of label i defined in html. Have you use the same html with mine? Do you still have errof for this?